# Build spring boot jar with a specific profile using maven

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot

Hi have a simple spring boot application that is deployed to the cloud
and i have the following application.yml file

```
server:
  port: 555
---

logging:
  path: logs
  level.com.datasol: DEBUG
---

security:
  user.password: pass
---

spring:
  profiles.active: default,heroku

---
spring:
  profiles: default
  data.mongodb.uri: mongodb://user:pass@localhost/test

---

spring:
  profile: heroku
  data.mongodb.uri: mongodb://user:cloud_pass@hfg.mongolab.com:12345/test
```

When building with maven (clean package) do i have a pay to specify the usage of the 'heroku' profile 
i tried to add the profile in the maven command but i got the following

> The requested profile "heroku" could not be activated because it does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to resolve this by modifing the Procfile (needed by heroku) to include the following argument

> -Dspring.profiles.active=heroku

Comment: Yep, Spring profiles and Maven profiles are not the same :) Maven cannot "see" or use the Spring profiles. Only Spring can.
The `-Dspring.profiles.active` option you used is the way to pass Spring profiles through maven command lines.